# Python Buttons positions

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am currently trying to program a tic-tac-toe.
So first, i created 9 buttons that should fill the window.
But i can't manage to place them in such order. Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

tl=Button(root)
tm=Button(root)
tr=Button(root)
ml=Button(root)
mm=Button(root)
mr=Button(root)
ll=Button(root)
lm=Button(root)
lr=Button(root)

photo1=PhotoImage(file="/Users/apple/Desktop/images Tkinter/arrowhead.gif")
photo2=PhotoImage(file="/Users/apple/Desktop/images     Tkinter/arrowhead_plus.gif")
photo3=PhotoImage(file="/Users/apple/Desktop/images Tkinter/arrowhead_circle.gif")

tl.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
tl.pack(side='top',anchor='nw')

tm.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
tm.pack(side='top',anchor='n')

tr.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
tr.pack(side='top',anchor='ne')

ml.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
ml.pack(anchor='w')

mm.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
mm.pack(anchor='center')

mr.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
mr.pack(anchor='e')

ll.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
ll.pack(anchor='sw')

lm.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
lm.pack(anchor='s')

lr.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
lr.pack(anchor='se')

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggested only using `Widget.pack()` for quick prototyping; just to make sure everything is working. For a tic-tac-toe game grid is very convenient. Just specifiy the row and column as such, `Widget.grid(row=#, column=#)` More on TkInter's grid system  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm).

Comment: Thank you Ben, the 'row' and 'column' are working pretty well.

Comment: `pack` is great for more than just rapid prototyping. However, using `grid` for displaying widgets in a grid is definitely the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `pack()`; use `grid()`.  For example, `button.grid(row=0, column=1)`